# Provisional headers are shown - need to fix that

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I am using in the MAMP server (Apache 2.0 Handler). I try to build a website using html, js, css, jquery and ajax. Before this project everything works fine but now the post Request doesn't work correctly.

I'm getting the following warning:

> "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED"

Show in this line (ajax):

```
   request.send(null); // for POST only
```

This is what I get in the header network windows (in Chrome):

```
Request URL: file:///C:/MAMP/htdocs/dad/snip/home.html
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Provisional headers are shown
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36
```

My JavaScript (ajax):

```
(function (global) {

// Set up a namespace for our utility
var ajaxUtils = {};


// Returns an HTTP request object
function getRequestObject() {
if (global.XMLHttpRequest) {
return (new XMLHttpRequest());
} 
else if (global.ActiveXObject) {
// For very old IE browsers (optional)
return (new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
} 
else {
global.alert("Ajax is not supported!");
return(null); 
}
}


// Makes an Ajax GET request to 'requestUrl'
ajaxUtils.sendGetRequest = 
function(requestUrl, responseHandler, isJsonResponse) {
var request = getRequestObject();
request.onreadystatechange = 
function() { 
handleResponse(request, 
responseHandler,
isJsonResponse); 
};
request.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
request.send(null); // for POST only
};

// Only calls user provided 'responseHandler'
// function if response is ready
// and not an error
function handleResponse(request,
responseHandler,
isJsonResponse) {
if ((request.readyState == 4) &&
(request.status == 200)) {

// Default to isJsonResponse = true
if (isJsonResponse == undefined) {
isJsonResponse = true;
}

if (isJsonResponse) {
responseHandler(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
}
else {
responseHandler(request.responseText);
}
}
}

// Expose utility to the global object
global.$ajaxUtils = ajaxUtils;

})(window);


------------------------------------------------------------------------
//my ajax calling in anothe js file 
// On page load (before images or CSS)
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {

  // On first load, show home view
  if(!check) {
    check = true;
    console.log(check);
    showLoading("#main-content");
    console.log(check);
    $ajaxUtils.sendGetRequest(homeHtml, function (responseText) {
      document.querySelector("#main-content").innerHTML = responseText;
    }, false);
    console.log(check);
  }
});
```

Comment: if you need some answers, I'd suggest you to provide a [mcve] and tidy your code (like I've edited indentation of the last bit). Showing your attempts to resolve the issue will increase your chances as well

Comment: You cannot request a local URL like `file:///C:/MAMP/htdocs/dad/snip/home.html` with Ajax.